# TensorFlow CIFAR10 cifar10_eval.py throws error: Compute status: Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the [SVHN](http://ufldl.stanford.edu/housenumbers/) data set on the CIFAR10 example provided in the TensorFlow packages. All I did was just to change the source directories for the data, and modify a few lines of code here and there. I can successfully train the network.

However, when I run svhn_eval.py (the equivalent of cifar10_eval.py, names changed so I know how to organize my files), I get this error of assign requires shape of both tensors to match. I guess that the problem could be due to

```
saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
```

as the trace ends there and goes deep into the other files of TensorFlow. Does anyone know how to solve this?

```
W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1076] 0x1a5bad0 Compute status: Invalid argument: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [2304,384] rhs shape= [4096,384]
     [[Node: save/Assign_5 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](local3/weights, save/restore_slice_5)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 161, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 157, in main
    evaluate()
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 147, in evaluate
    eval_once(saver, summary_writer, top_k_op, summary_op)
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 78, in eval_once
    saver.restore(sess, ckpt.model_checkpoint_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 891, in restore
    sess.run([self._restore_op_name], {self._filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 373, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 449, in _do_run
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: Assign requires shapes of both tensors to match. lhs shape= [2304,384] rhs shape= [4096,384]
     [[Node: save/Assign_5 = Assign[T=DT_FLOAT, use_locking=true, validate_shape=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](local3/weights, save/restore_slice_5)]]
Caused by op u'save/Assign_5', defined at:
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 161, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/default/_app.py", line 30, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 157, in main
    evaluate()
  File "/home/samuelchin/svhn/svhn_eval.py", line 137, in evaluate
    saver = tf.train.Saver(variables_to_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 713, in __init__
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 432, in build
    filename_tensor, vars_to_save, restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 202, in _AddRestoreOps
    validate_shape=not reshape))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_state_ops.py", line 40, in assign
    use_locking=use_locking, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 660, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1850, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1049, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

EDIT 1: The lines of code that I changed are in distorted_inputs. In the the original CIFAR10, there was random crop from a 32x32 to a 24x24 picture. However, in the SVHN implementation, I input 32x32 images. Based on the output error, we can sort of figure out what's wrong.

```
lhs shape= [2304,384] rhs shape= [4096,384]
2304 = 24 * 24 * 4
4096 = 32 * 32 * 4
```

The question we have to ask ourselves now is, why multiply by 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is that cifar10.py has a variable called IMAGE_SIZE. I left it as 24, because I thought it would not affect anything. However, what happens is that when you try and run the test set, the inputs are cropped to a size of IMAGE_SIZE x IMAGE_SIZE.

Therefore, when that wasn't changed, the tensor dimensions do not match. Changing that variable to 32 will do the trick.